# How to create an Octave function that evaluate the sum of pairs of numbers in the vector?

Tags: matlab, octave

It's like a reverse version of Pascal's triangle.
I want to create a vector-input function named 
`y = lastnum(vect)` on Octave, that evaluate the sum of each pair of numbers in any vectors to output the single number from the evaluation loops like this

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 3 5 7
4 8 12
12 20
32
```

And the input and output would be like this,

```
lastnum([0 1 2 3 4])
ans = 32
```

I mean... is there any progresses that I can do??? You may not understand but,  the reverse triangle above can guide you about my question.

I also tagged MATLAB since it has similar language. MATLAB pros may help my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the number of times each element gets added to produce the final result comes from Pascals triangle itself, so, e.g., for the vector `[a b c d]` the result will be `a+3b+3c+d`. So create a vector of entries in Pascals triangle and multiply and add with the original vector `v`.

I only have access to Matlab, Octave may not have all these functions.

This is a one-liner `diag(fliplr(pascal(numel(v)))).'*v(:)`.

Or a looping version

```
s = 0;
for i = 0:numel(v)-1
    s = s+nchoosek(numel(v)-1,i)*v(i+1);
end
s
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing I can think of is:

```
while length(x) > 0
    disp(x)
    x = x(1:end-1) + x(2:end);
end
```

or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: This is how I interpreted the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version for both MATLAB and Octave:

```
function y = lastnum(v)
  while 1
    if length(v) == 2
      y = sum(v)
      break;
    end
    # disp(v); # if you want to print the progress
    vt = [];
    for k = 1:(length(v)-1)
      vt(end+1) = sum(v(k:(k+1)));
    end
    v = vt;
  end
end
```